# How do I calculate MB/s & MiB/s?

Tags: c

I've recently discovered that MB/s is technically equivalent to 8 million bits/s
and not 1024<sup>2</sup> bits per second which should be called a Mebibyte.

This should be easy, but when comparing output from various sources I get different answers, even from google which thinks there is no difference at all between the measures.

If I transfer 1381530 bytes in 17797601 nanoseconds, what is the data rate in those two measures? and what is the formula you're using to calculate it?

Currently I have: where duration is in nanoseconds.

```
double data_rate_MiBps = (num_bytes/1024/1000) / ((double)duration * 1e-9);
double data_rate_MBps = (num_bytes/1024/1024) / ((double)duration * 1e-9);
```

Thanks for the responses.  I was ending up with numbers that didn't make sense before but now they do.   The above code should be the following:

```
double data_rate_MiBps = (num_bytes/1024.0/1000.0) / ((double)duration * 1e-9);
double data_rate_MBps = (num_bytes/1024.0/1024.0) / ((double)duration * 1e-9);
```

I therefore get:

```
74.085 MiB/s
75.863 MB/s
```

Which I think makes sense.

Probably a better question.  Why in the first place was 1024 bytes chosen to be 1KB instead of 1000.  Since Kilo (etc) = 1000 everywhere else.

Comment: @AdrianCornish - thought I could, but I'm not the only one having issues.  At least 2 online converters give different answers!

Comment: there is a difference in how the world views a megabyte http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: You should at least be consistent with your Mibps measurement. If a megabyte is 1000 kilobytes, you might as well consider that a kilobyte is 1000 bytes rather than 1024.

Comment: Data rates are in Mbps, not MB/s.  Bits, not bytes.  Everybody makes it look as good as possible so they use megabits (10^6), not mebibits (2^20).  Bits is a common fib too, it includes all framing and error checking overhead, not just the data.

Comment: This data rate is calculated on pure data. Thanks for the info Hans.

Comment: I asked this question because I was trying to see how close I could get to theoretical maximum bandwidth of the infiniband network I was using. Turned out windows kernel was an issue.  Locking memory to prevent paging etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> If I transfer 1381530 bytes in 17797601 nanoseconds, what is the data rate in those two measures?

0.0776 bytes/ns.

First, careful:

> I've recently discovered that MB/s is technically equivalent to 8000 million bits/s

I've never heard of this definition.

"MB/s" *usually* means "megabytes per second". This can be *one of two definitions*, depending on who you ask:

- 1 million bytes per second (8 million bits per second) (per the IEEE's definition)
- The more commonly seen definition of 1024 * 1024 (1048576) bytes per second (8388608 bits per second), seen commonly in many usages.

In some really, really rare cases, "MB/s" *could* mean "megabits per second", but megabits per second is usually abbreviated to "Mbps" or "Mbits/s". The context will most often clue you in on which is appropriate: wireless transmission speeds, ethernet cards, etc. are typically measured in megabits per second; file transfers over the internet are measured in megabytes (or mebibyte, see next paragraph) per second.

The IEEE has proposed that computers should follow the SI prefixes, and use "Kilobyte" to mean 10<sup>3</sup> bytes, not 2<sup>10</sup> bytes, which has been done historically. (And thus created all the confusion over which definition of a megabyte one is actually using.) However, in many contexts, 10<sup>3</sup> makes little sense, so different "binary" prefixes were introduced, such as the "Kibibyte", which is abbreviated KiB and *always* means 1024 bytes. In your case, there is it "Mebibyte", or MiB (and when per second, MiB/s) and means 1024*1024 bytes.

See the [Wikipedia article on the Megabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) for more info.

(For the conversions to bits/s, I've assumed 8 bits/byte.)

Comment: I like this answer.  It depends on who you talk to.  Therefore if I use the SI prefix there should be no ambiguity.

Answer (score 24):

See

1>  **Megabyte per second**

A megabyte per second (MB/s or MBps) is a unit of data transfer rate equal to:

1,000,000 bytes per second,

2> **Megabit per second**

A megabit per second (Mbit/s, Mb/s, or Mbps) is a unit of data transfer rate equal to:

1,000,000 bits per second

**3>Mebibyte per second**

A mebibyte per second (MiB/s or MiBps) is a unit of data transfer rate equal to:

1,048,576 bytes per second, or

**4>Mebibit per second**

A mebibit per second (Mibit/s or Mib/s) is a unit of data transfer rate equal to:

1,048,576 bits per second or

Answer (score 3):

*Probably a better question. Why in the first place was 1024 bytes chosen to be 1KB instead of 1000? Since Kilo (etc) = 1000 everywhere else.*

The prefixes Kilo, Mega, Giga, and Tera come from the metric system, which was designed to use powers of 10, since we all use base 10. But computers use base 2, so quantities are better defined as powers of 2 rather than 10. By coincidence, 2<sup>10</sup> is roughly equal to 10<sup>3</sup>. So computer professionals started referring to 2<sup>10</sup> as Kilo, and 2<sup>20</sup> as Mega, and so on. Integer values are expressed as values using 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, which are also powers of 2. Memory addresses are bound at powers of 2. So 16 bits of address space can access 2<sup>16</sup> bytes of memory. Also, since a 32-bit processor can access 2<sup>32</sup> addresses, or 2<sup>2</sup> Giga-addresses of 8 bits each, it can use 4 gigabytes of memory. This is why memory chips come in sizes like 1GB which means 2<sup>30</sup> bytes.

So, when referring to values that are better measured as powers of 2, it makes more sense to define kilo, mega, and giga as 2<sup>10</sup>, 2<sup>20</sup>, and 2<sup>30</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

10<sup>3</sup> = Kilo

10<sup>6</sup> = Mega/Million

10<sup>9</sup> = Giga/Billion

That's what you should have already taught in school. But when you're calculating Bytes, the calculations are slightly different:

2<sup>10</sup> bytes = 1024 bytes = 1 Kilobyte

2<sup>20</sup> bytes = 1024<sup>2</sup> bytes = 1 Megabyte

2<sup>30</sup> bytes = 1024<sup>3</sup> bytes = 1 Gigabyte

Of course, no one will blame you if you use 10<sup>6</sup> bytes as 1 Megabyte. HDD manufactures use 10<sup>9</sup> bytes as 1 Gigabyte.

To make calculations unambiguous, MiB/s (or GiB/s) is often used instead of MB/s (or GB/s) when referring to bytes. Thus, 1 MiB/s actually means 1024<sup>2</sup> bytes per second. Yet, you'll see many areas where simply MB is used to indicate 1024<sup>2</sup> bytes (e.g., Windows).

Now, it's upto you how you calculate MB/s. If you use MiB/s, then you should stick to the convention and use 1024<sup>2</sup> instead of 10<sup>6</sup>.

Comment: Yet, the calculation _should_ not be different. We traditionally divide by 1024 because there was a time at which processors had no hardware division instruction, and shifting 10 bits right was 'close enough'. This is obviously not true anymore. Also, today, most hard drive vendors use the decimal meaning of kilo, mega and giga; and at least Mac OS does so since a few years, too.

Comment: i agree. everyone should stick to a convention. there was a time when i used to lost with these calculations. now, i've accepted the 2^x convention for computers.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that mega is an SI prefix unit so it is technically should refer to 1 000 000 bytes, while the mebi prefix should refer to 2<sup>20</sup>.

Online converters do not always follow modern standard since until recently a lot of people, hardware companies, and OSes confuses the definition of mega and uses it for the binary prefix sometimes inconsistently.

Answer (score 0):

They use 1024 instead of 1000 because its divisible by 2. Computers are binary and they calculate bytes by multiplying by 2. Where they start by multiply 2 by 2 and getting 4 and doubling that to 8 and so on till you get to 1024 next would be 2048 and then 4096.